Seeking an elementry theorem about lattices.
I am doing some work with objects. Each object has a corresponding embedded free $\mathbb Z$-module, with important properties of the object being related to whether the embedding is a lattice. From this fact a theorem of mine could potentially be simplified by expressing it as corollary a nicer theorem in lattice theory. However I don't know very much about lattices.
The statement of the potential theorem is as follows:

Let $\Lambda$ be an embedding of a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module in $\mathbb{R}^d$. If the rank of $\Lambda$ is greater than $d$ then $\Lambda$ is not discrete.

It might happen that this theorem is false. I don't have a good intuition for lattices, and my thinking is probably poisoned by the fact that the embeddings I am concerned with definitely obey this theorem. There might be some precondition I need to slap on to make it true.
Is this a known theorem in lattice theory?
I'm ideally looking for a reference rather than just a proof. If it's false a counter-example would help me to correct the theorem.
I skimmed through the early chapters of An introduction to the geometry of numbers and Sphere packings, lattices, and groups, the former seems more relevant to me, but I wasn't able to find a statement of the theorem in either.

I do not know an "original" reference, but I can assure you that, yes, there is a classification of discrete subgroups of $\mathbb R^n$, and they are all free $\mathbb Z$-modules of rank at most $n$. This is not entirely trivial to prove, but is not un-natural. Again, I do not know an "original" ref, but a proof is written out at https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/discrete_sbgps.pdf
